# Pure HTML and CSS hamburger menu does not work

Tags: html, css, hamburger-menu

I'm making a hamburger menu right now with html and css (no js), and the :checked + .something does not work. I'm searching for solutions for about 3 hours but i can't find any. If you would help me that would be nice.
Maybe I messed up somewhere because i watched it from a video, but i did the exact same thing like him but i doesn't work :(
Here is the code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.navigations {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navigations div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navigations a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.burger {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}

#toggle:checked+.navigations {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="something.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="navigations">
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="">About us</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="">Tours</a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="">Contacts</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <label for="toggle">
      <div class="burger">
          <div class="burgerelem"></div>
          <div class="burgerelem"></div>
          <div class="burgerelem"></div>
      </div>
  </label>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you add working snippet code so it would be good to solve.

Comment: I made a site like the other but it does not work too, here you go

Comment: You have removed the `input` from your example. Also, `+` is the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator). Your `#toggle` element would need to be directly _before_ the `.navigations` element in the HTML for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're actually missing the checkbox element. Since you're using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), (`+` in `#toggle:checked + .navigations`) you should put the checkbox with the `.navigations` div *immediately before* the `#toggle` input.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: teal;
}

.navigations {
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 150px;
  border-radius: 50px 10px 10px 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navigations div {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.navigations a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.burger {
  z-index: 100;
  position: fixed;
  right: 25px;
  display: block;
  top: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div {
  width: 45px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#toggle {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
}

/*
    Since the .navigations is the next sibling element after #toggle,
    the + selector works here
*/

#toggle:checked+.navigations {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" /> <!-- Add this! -->
<div class="navigations">
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="">About us</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="">Tours</a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <a href="">Contacts</a>
  </div>
</div>
<label for="toggle">
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="burgerelem"></div>
    <div class="burgerelem"></div>
    <div class="burgerelem"></div>
  </div>
</label>
```